# Rest service at one instance of Cloud Foundry at one point of time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have one Rest service running in PCF.It might take 10-15mins to complete.PCF app is configured to run on multiple instances.

I want to make sure at a single point of time,that Rest service to run only in one instance. e.g: if the Rest service running in one instance and I try to call the same service multiple times then it should not be taken by any other instance, rather it should wait till it's completion and then it can run in any other or same instance.

Kindly suggest some best practices to this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use cf route services which act as a reverse proxy to rate  limit the request to be executed only one at a time ...one example can be found here https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/ratelimit-service

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Can you expand on your use case & requirements? It kind of sounds like you have multiple instances of an application running and you want to pin traffic to a single app instance? but I may be misunderstanding.

Comment: @Daniel Mikusa, Your understanding is right ! I want to have multiple instances of app in PCF and I want to pin the traffic to single app and until the process is not completed in that instance other instance should not take the new request. Something like Semaphore but semaphore is JVM specific. I am thinking of using external DB to store process status and based on that it will stop executing the process but looking for any better solution.

Comment: I don't think you want to design it that way. The foundation can't help you make those guarantees and it seems very difficult to scale. I would suggest you make your application so that it takes requests in a lightweight manner, like have it accept but not process the request. Then communicate with some workers who receive the request and do the actual work. @Stephen Dillion suggests queues, which is a good option, but I think you could swap that for your shared service of choice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a prime use case for a message queue. Have any app accept the request and add it to the queue, then a free listener in any app can consume the message. If you are scaling a lot and it's a intensive task it might even be recommendable to split the produce and consumer into separate apps, so a intensive consumer doesn't make you api unresponsive

Comment: Cloud Foundry offers a feature that can make this pattern easier. Instead of having two separate applications, you can use the multiple process feature -> https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/multiple-processes.html. It is convenient if you have the same code base for the producer & consumer.